# Android Form Reset?

Tags: android

I have a simple calculator that has six EditText views where users will enter numbers to perform a simple math function. This app will satisfy a repetitive task wherein the users will enter the information, press the submit button and the answer is displayed in a separate textView.

I want to add a simple 'clear' button that will reset the form so the users can begin a new calculation and the EditText views will show their hints for user input once again.

Is there a 'reset' type function that will clear all of the form data and reload the hints or do I have to kill the app and start it again? If so, whats a good starting place for how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The most basic way to do this would be to simply reset your `EditText` views.  If you have logic that drives the update of these fields, then resetting them to an empty `String` and requesting a "recalculation" to update the hints.

Something like this:

```
private void onClear()
{
    EditText firstField = (EditText)this.findById(R.id.firstField);
    EditText secondField = (EditText)this.findById(R.id.secondField);
    //...etc...
    if (firstField != null) firstField.setText("");
    if (secondField != null) secondField.setText("");

    updateHints();
}

private void updateHints()
{
    //Logic for your "hints"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to implement it yourself. I suggest you create an int array with the IDs of all your `EditTexts` you want to reset (`R.id.xyz`).  Then create a loop to `.setText()` to each of the EditTexts from the array, which you can call every time you want the fields to be cleared. Something like:

```
private void resetFields() {
    EditText temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < myEditTexts.length; i++) {
            temp = (EditText) findViewById(textViews[i]);
        temp.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is just a better way but it still a kind of hard code. Anyone could find another way faster, please share.

```
protected void clearForm() {
    Button btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clear_text);
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText temp;      
            final int[] txtId = new int[] {
                R.id.txt_s_free_word,
                R.id.txt_s_property_name,
                R.id.txt_s_ad_expense_from,
                R.id.txt_s_ad_expense_to,
                R.id.txt_s_station
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < txtId.length; i++) {
                temp = (EditText) findViewById(txtId[i]);
                temp.setText(null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```