# Implementing a reset button in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Form Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013228/android-form-reset)

I am developing a form in which I have submit and reset buttons. How can I make the reset button clear all of the fields of the form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register an `OnClickListener` to the button, and in it set the text of each field to its default:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myFirstField.setText("default text of field");
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a reset button in Android like there is for HTML.  You will have to implement the click handler and clear all the data yourself...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this goal is to iterate over `EditText` (or `TextView`) objects and use the setText() method with a "" parameter - this will simply set the text of these objects to an empty string. Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention where you are using.Use this for android.

```
          startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class));
```